# My component is not re-render, I am mutating the state.?

Tags: react-redux

I have two actions that affect an array of objects in the redux store.
The first changes the dimensions of the array and the properties of the objects within it, everything works fine.
the second only modifies some properties of one of the objects in the array. this works fine but the component is not rendered with the new changes.

the following code represents the reducer of the second action (the action that does not render the component).

```
case 'UPDATE': {
   return {
      ...state,
      arrayOfObjects: state.arrayOfObjects.map(
         (ítem,i)=> i===action.index ? {
               ...ítem,
               images: action.images,
            } : {...item}
      ),
   }
}
```

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624056/5124488?

Comment: Try this: `case"UPDATE":return{...state,arrayOfObjects:{...state.arrayOfObjects,[state.arrayOfObjects[action.index].images]:action.images}}`

Comment: Hi Kyle, I appreciate your comment, but there is a small detail, your solution returns an object and not an array of objects as I need. What changes do I have to make to achieve this.

Comment: ok I already did it but the component is not rendered with the new images